# Keep only certain rows in excel - vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have to keep only certain rows in an excel file.
Basically when I have 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
I have to keep rows number: 1,4,7,10 and I have to delete all the others
How can I do it?

**UPDATE Code attempt**

```
Sub Macro1() ' ' 
    Range("A1").Select 
    Dim rng As Range 
    Dim InputRng As Range 
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection 
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8) 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    For i = 1 To InputRng.Rows.Count 
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete 
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete 
    Next 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you looked at the method `.EntireRow.Delete`?

Comment: Have a look at hide rows or post an attempt

Comment: Yes, But I don't know how can I delete rows 2 and 3 (logically speaking), that's why I'm looking for a "keep" method.

Comment: I solved it like that:
Sub Macro1()
'
'
    Range("A1").Select
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To InputRng.Rows.Count
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

I don't know whether there are more efficient ways... still it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this Assuming you have your sheets with the code name Sheet1 and Sheet2:

```
Sub CopyRows()
With Sheet1
    .Range("1:1,4:4,7:7,10:10").Copy
    Sheet2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    .Cells.Delete
    Sheet2.Range("1:4").Copy .Range("A1")
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It tells me that the object is necessary (don't know if it's correct as I'm not using excel in english).

Comment: Since `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` weren't defined & set in the sample, replace `Sheet1` with `Sheets("Sheet1")` and `Sheet2` with `Sheets("Sheet2")`. That's not the best way to do it, but it's a quick fix that should get you moving forward without rewriting the sample code.